# Stop rails subdomain from triggering on *everything*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, subdomain

My site has some pages, such as `example.com/about`

I have also created an API for my app at `api.example.com`.

```
# API                                                           
namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do 
  scope format: true, constraints: { format: 'json' } do        
    get 'posts/latest', to: 'posts#latest'                      
    get 'posts/:id',    to: 'posts#show'                        
  end                                                           
end 

# Pages
get 'about'    to: 'pages#about'
get 'contact', to: 'pages#contact'
```

The problem is, now my `/about` page is working on my api subdomain.

`api.example.com/about` should definitely not work like that, and should trigger a 404.

What I really want to do is wrap the entire rest of my routes file in `constraints: { subdomain: nil }` but I want to know the "Rails Way" to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason why you're going with a subdomain route instead of just using your namespacing? The crappy thing about having too many subdomains is that you will most likely either need to obtain/manage multiple SSL certificates and/or purchase a wildcard certificate. Neither are that big of a deal, but wasn't sure of your reasoning behind the subdomain route.

Comment: load balancing at the DNS level mainly

Comment: Gotcha. I usually use HAProxy to route traffic to different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I really want to do is wrap the entire rest of my routes file in `constraints: { subdomain: nil }` but I want to know the "Rails Way" to do this.

**This *is* the Rails way.**

A typical Rails app will just listen to a socket and not care about domains. Usually your webserver will handle the mapping between domains/IP addresses and internal application sockets (e.g. Apache VirtualHost).

When the webserver passes an HTTP request to the application, Rails then is only interested in everything *but* the (sub-) domain, unless configured otherwise.